# `]` key doesn't work in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome on my HP Spectre x360 laptop.

I tried to type in the character `]` using my keyboard and several applications bit it doesn't work. However, pressing shift works and gives me the characters `}`. It also works without problem in Gnome activities search.

The key doesn't work with my laptop keyboard nor with my external Logitech keyboard and it doesn't work with other keyboard layouts(I've tried En-US, En-Uk and Czech).

This problem doesn't occur on Windows on the same laptop.

This was happening to me since I've installed Ubuntu.

Comment: Is the computer in dual boot? If so, did it work when booting in different OS? Try starting from USB with OS installed on USB key. Does the key work? In none of the attempts above work, I would say you have a hardware issue that coincided with you installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Please specify which keyboard layout you're using.

Comment: @JuanAntonio I do have dual boot and I have no problems in Windows.

Comment: @UTF-8 English US, English UK and one local.

Comment: I suggest  that before trying anything else, you check the  Keyboard Shortcuts setting in  `System Settings` Check if `]` is assigned to some shortcut. As absurd as it seems, [this does happen](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2189571)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R.S was right! ] - was actually shortcut for maximize window so I disabled it!

I've never tried it while having non maximized window plus the key worked when searching for something.